# Histogram as stacked bar chart based on categories

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, histogram, visualization

I have data with a numeric and categorical variable. I want to show a histogram of the numeric column, where each bar is stacked by the categorical variable. I tried to do this with `ax.hist(data, histtype='bar', stacked=True)`, but couldn't quite get it to work.

If my data is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': np.random.normal(45, 5, 100), 'job': np.random.choice(['engineer', 'barista', 
                   'quantity surveyor'], size=100)})
```

I've organised it like this:

```
df['binned_age'] = pd.qcut(df.age, 5)
df.groupby('binned_age')['job'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Which gives me a bar chart divided the way I want, but side by side, not stacked, and without different colours for each category.

[image]

Is there a way to stack this plot? Or just do it a regular histogram, but stacked by category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you will need to reshape your dataset first - i will do that using `pivot_table` and use `len` for an aggregator as that will give you the frequency.

Then you can use a similar code to the one you provided above.

```
df.drop('age',axis=1,inplace=True)
df_reshaped = df.pivot_table(index=['binned_age'], columns=['job'], aggfunc=len)

df_reshaped.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ylabel='Frequency', xlabel='Age binned',
         title='Age group frequency by Job', rot=45)
```

prints:

[image]

You can use the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html) to tailor the chart to your needs

Answer (score 1):

```
df['age_bin'] = pd.cut(df['age'], [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70])
df.groupby('age_bin')['job'].value_counts().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: I modified your answer a little (and removed some redundant parts) but yeah, this is pretty much what I wanted.